# post json return empty values

Tags: jquery, json

I am using json to create a modal, I am using this code to pass variable to Stored Procedure that return the code using `json_encode()`
My issue is that the json is returning nothing.

I am using this code:

```
$('table.mytable').on('click', '.edit-row', function () {
$("#ProjectID").val($(this).data('projectid'));
$("#StepID").val($(this).data('stepid'));

$.post('', {GetList: 1, ProjectID: $(this).data('projectid'), StepID: $(this).data('stepid')}, function (data) {
var html = '';
$.each(data, function (index, value)
{
   html += '          <tr> ';
   html += '               <td> '+ value.value1 +' </td>\
                           <td> '+ value.value2 +' </td>\
                           <td> '+ value.value3 +'</td>';
   html += '           <tr>';
 });
 $('table#my-tb > tbody').html(html);

    }, 'json');
 });
```

Comment: There might be data but not in the form you expect? Try doing console.log(data) just above "var html... ". Anything there?

Comment: @Anders the result of the console.log is Array(0)

Comment: So it is an array - just like you want, but it is empty. So problem lies on server side. Are you sure you are hitting the right url? First parameter: ''

Comment: When i change the first parameter to the page url - which is the same page the post is on - the console.log results is []

Comment: @Anders .. the `$.post` is not sending data the same page at the moment